# How to add a conversation on the TweetDeck?

Tags: twitter, tweetdeck

Say, I have a huge thread consisting of an original tweet and a multitude of replies. How can I add all of those to a TweetDeck column?

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution. It's not perfect but it does the job. What you'll have to do is:

1. Copy the exact text of the original tweet you wish to open in a dedicated column
2. On Tweetdeck, click the `+` button on left menue" to add a new column
3. From the popup, select the "search" option.
4. In the search box, construct the following query: `from:[orriginal_tweet_author] "[paste_orriginal_tweet_text]"` and click the  to create the column.
5. The new column will now present the original tweet. Click it once and you'll get all the multitude of replies, all in one column.